# INSERT statement not working mysql

Tags: php, mysql

When I process this data, the data is not being inserted into my database. This is my current database structure:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzJ9StkJe55WaG1oaVhqcUJmSGc/edit?usp=sharing

I have no clue why it is not inserting. I am not getting an error message and I am seeing the successfully inserted data piece.

```
<head><title>Process Punch</title></head>

<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'name');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_HOST', 'host');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link){
    die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}else{

$userid_value = $_POST['userid'];
$punchtype_value = $_POST['punchtype'];
$group_value = $_POST['group'];
$dept_value = $_POST['dept'];
$notes_value = $_POST['notes'];
$table = "tc_".$userid_value;
$date_value = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
echo $table;
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (punchtype, groupname, dept, notes) VALUES ('$punchtype_value',     '$group_value', '$dept_value', '$notes_value')";
echo "Successfully inserted data";

}
?>
```

Comment: could you give us the error note?

Comment: I am not getting one.

Comment: $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $link );

Comment: what? I have no clue what that means.

Comment: You have defined your query in `$sql` variable. But to execute it, you must run the query. You must use `mysql_query`. However `mysql` is outdated, so use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Comment: This was working a lot better before you "fixed" it and created a massive [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/) because of recklessly bad [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, stop using `mysql_query` before it costs you severely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the query with mysql_query(), concatenate the query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `".$table."` (`punchtype`, `groupname`, `dept`, `notes`) VALUES ('".$punchtype_value."',       '".$group_value."', '".$dept_value."', '".$notes_value."')";
$qry = mysql_query($sql ,$link);
echo "Successfully inserted data";
```

Comment: Thanks too and one more thing is change your drive from mysql to mysqli or PDO. mysql will be going to deprecate http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet. sorry.